# Which way is better to identify UI controls in Automated testing: Automation ID or Class-Label-Index

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

For UI automation of desktop applications the interested UI control is located with parent child hierarchy and at the hierarchy Class-Label-Index is used to identify the object uniquely. Recently I came across Automation ID which is part of UI automation. My question here is:

1. Which is the best practice Class-Label-Index or Automation ID?
2. How consistent is the Automation ID? As I have seen it can be only numbers, only alpha or alphanumeric as well.
3. Is Automation ID persistent across multiple versions of the same app?
4. As I understood Automation ID is the property of the C# apps, this is not available with apps developed with other technologies like Java. Am I correct here?

Answer (score -1):

Usually if the AutomationID property is number then it may be dynamic number.  Please note down the AutomationID and re-launch the  same application and see it display the same number.  If the number is different then its dynamic id.

If the it is dynamic id then it  is not recommended to use this AutomationID.  You need to find out the property which is fixed.  Like Name, Class, Control.Type etc.